# Laravel add text to variable in Controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am sorry this might be a foolish question, but I am trying to download pdf files, and everything find just the name of pdf

my controller

```
$abstract = Project::find($A_ID);
$pdf = PDF::loadView('Abstracts.pdf', compact('abstract'));
return $pdf->download('abstract.pdf'); //name of the pdf
```

what I am trying to do is to change the `('abstract.pdf')` to `($abstract->A_Title)`

The issue with `($abstract->A_Title)` it doesn't have `.pdf` extension, and I have been trying to add it with no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [concatenation](https://www.w3schools.in/php/operators/concatenation-operators/) `(.)`operator here

for example :

```
$name = "title"; 
$extension = ".pdf";

$fileName = $name . $extenstion;
```

> $fileName output should be **title.pdf**

```
$abstract = Project::find($A_ID);
$pdf = PDF::loadView($abstract->A_Title.'.pdf', compact('abstract'));
return $pdf->download($abstract->A_Title.'.pdf'); //name of the pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP concatenation,

```
$abstract = Project::find($A_ID);
$pdf = PDF::loadView($abstract->A_Title.'.pdf', compact('abstract'));
return $pdf->download($abstract->A_Title.'.pdf');
```